# Can't get Rails db console working with psql

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have a Rails 3.0.7 running on Mac OSX Snow Leapard.

The database works and the site is up and running.

I went to try out the new rails db console and it produced the following error:

```
Couldn't find database client: psql. Check your $PATH and try again.
```

When I try:

$ which psql

it returns nothing.

Here is my .profile bash file:

```
export PATH="$HOME/ImageMagick-6.6.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin::$PATH"
export SQL_PATH=$HOME/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1
export MAGICK_HOME="$HOME/ImageMagick-6.6.9"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$MAGICK_HOME/lib/"
 # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

I am exporing the path for Postgres.

How can I get the Rails db to find my psql?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To your `.profile` bash file, add the following:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/pgsql/bin
```

Replace the path `/usr/lib/pgsql/bin` with the path to your pgsql bin.

Comment: Thanks Jatin, could you check this PATH=$PATH:~/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin is this right? It seems PostgreSQL installed in my Library directory.

Answer (score 5):

I'm on **Mac**, with **Postgres.app**.

I updated my .bash_profile like this

```
open ~/.bash_profile
```

adding

```
PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin
```

- Check where your Postgress.app is

Answer (score 2):

If you installed psql using homebrew try the following:

`brew unlink postgresql`

then follow that up with

`brew link postgresql`

Now try running rails dbconsole again